# Find difference between arrays in Ruby, where the elements are hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two arrays of hashes I would like to find the difference between.  My issue is the array elements are single item hashes.

So far, using `array1 - array2` appears to be working correctly but do I need to watch out for gotchas here?  The hash elements themselves read like `h = {'ID' => '76322'}`, where the numeric value differs from hash to hash, so nothing too fancy.

[EDIT]

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
array1 = []
array2 = []

h = {'ID' => '76322'}
array1.push(h)

h = {'ID' => '7891'}
array1.push(h)
array2.push(h)

array1 = array1 - array2 # should result in array1 having a single hash of values {'ID', '76322'}
```

Comment: Give example input and expected output..please..

Comment: and what you want now ? You told *Find difference between arrays in Ruby*. I requested to you to share the content of those 2 arrays..

Comment: put it in your question please..

Comment: as per your example you will get `[]` in your `array1`.

Comment: ok, they're in the question now.

Comment: `array1 - array2` will yield `[]`,by what logic you want `{'ID', '76322'}` ?

Comment: I pushed two elements into array1, and only one into array2.  Why would subtracting them result in array1 having no elements?

Comment: @Babai: You are very wrong. Run the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array1 - array2` works by putting the elements of `array2` into a temporary hash, then returning all elements of `array1` that don't appear in the hash. Hash elements are compared using `==` to determine whether they match.

Comparing two hashes with `==` gives `true` if all the keys and values of the hashes match using `==`. So

```
h1 = {'ID' => '7891'}
h2 = {'ID' => '7891'}
h1 == h2
```

evaluates to `true`, even though `h1` and `h2` are different hashes, and the corresponding elements will be correctly removed.

The only consideration I can think of is if you *always* have strings everywhere in the hash keys and values. If they are sometimes integers, or symbols, like `{:ID => 7891}` then you aren't going to get the results you want, because `:ID == 'ID'` and `'7891' == 7891` are both *`false`*.